# generating table code first not generating table on application run

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a site. using COde first. My add-migration command producted following code.

```
public partial class StudentEntity : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {



        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Student",
            c => new
                {
                    id = c.Int( nullable: false, identity: true),
                    name = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);


    }
```

Now I want to deploy my site so when site runs the first time I want the Student table to get generated in DB(SQL server).

Right now when I run the site it does not create any table. How can I do this? I dont want any seed data to initialize with

My db context class

```
  public partial class flagen:DbContext
{
    public flagen() : base("name=cf2")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
    //old entity
    public virtual DbSet<flag> flags { get; set; }
    //new entity
     public virtual DbSet<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

Then I tried to use Context so table get created. It throws error "The model backing the 'flagen' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database "
The I added following two lines to dbcontext class

```
  Database.SetInitializer<flagen>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

now it says "invalid object name students"

any solution that works?

Comment: EF doesn't initialise when a site starts up, it runs when you first try to use your context. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @DavidG its giving me following error when I first try to use context:"The model backing the 'flagen' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

Comment: And this is now a different question...

Comment: @DavidG updated question

Comment: And now we have a third, different question. You can't keep mutating your question like this.

Comment: @DavidG Ok can you answer it

Comment: I probably could, but because you have changed the question so many times I'm reluctant to do it as my answer would become irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidG the original question still unchanged

Comment: The original question was about the migration not running, now it is.

Comment: @DavidG no it was about table not generating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of this question is to use T4 templates. After searching the web I got the answer that nobody could on SO. Shame...

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=t4dacfx2tsql

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to define a Initializer that will migrate your database to last existing migration you added. Therefore all tables will be created and the Seed method of the Configuration will be executed too - you could use it for seeding data.
With the following example your database will be updated to last existing migration (and therefore creates all tables) on first initialization of the data context. (`var dbContext = new MyDatabaseContext()`)
In my opinion a much cleaner way than to use `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` that you could check out too. ;)

As mentioned here is an example that will use the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer with the defined behavior.

```
public partial class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Student> students { get; set; }



    public MyDatabaseContext() : base("MyDatabaseContextConnectionString")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDatabaseContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // here we want to define the entities structure
    }    
}
```

You will find some more information about the initializer itself [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh829293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (*MSDN 
 - MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion*) and [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx) (*Entity Framework Tutorial - Code-First Tutorials - Automated Migration*) is another example with some more background information and examples.